# GWT and SQL - No Suitable Driver

Tags: java, mysql, gwt

I'm currently having a very strange problem with GWT and SQL.

I'm trying to get my GWT program to communicate with my SQL server.  I took several examples from the web and they would all terminate with the following error:

```
SEVERE: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/table
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/table
```

After racking my brain for hours and hours, I finally came up with the following code which *DOES* work.  Running the following will happily output the MySQL version to the console:

```
public static void printVersion() {

    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/table";
    String user = "username";
    String password = "password";

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT VERSION()");

        if (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Version.class.getName());
        lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);

    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (st != null) {
                st.close();
            }
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Version.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

However, as soon as I changed the method slightly from outputting the string to the console to returning the string to a calling function, I started getting the "No suitable driver found" error again.

The change I made was *extremely* subtle; Here is the diff:

```
    1c1
<   public static String getVersion() {
---
>   public static void printVersion() {
10d9
<       String rtn = null;
18c17
<               rtn = rs.getString(1);
---
>               System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
42d40
<       return rtn;
```

The calling function simply changed from an `Version.printVersion()` to `String str = Version.getVersion()`.

I'm fairly experienced in PHP and am just making the jump to GWT/Java.  I searched all over and haven't been able to find out why this isn't working like it should.  Numerous tutorials and pre-existing code have failed me, so I'm asking here.

I *do* have the MySQL JDBC driver in my classpath, and I have tried several permutations loading it with `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();`, but to no avail

I'm sure I'm missing something really stupid, but I'm too inexperienced to have any clue what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I honestly don't know why the `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();` wasn't working before.  I tried several methods with that and none of them worked.  (I have since deleted my non-working work, so I can't compare why it didn't work)  I did try it in this example just now though and it does appear to work when added.  Here is the diff:

```
1c1
<   public static String getVersion() {
---
>   public static void printVersion() {
10d9
<       String rtn = null;
13d11
<           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
19c17
<               rtn = rs.getString(1);
---
>               System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
43d40
<       return rtn;
```

Basically just add the `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();` right before you initialize the connection.

I have absolutely ZERO idea why it *would* work without that statement if I'm just printing the output but *wouldn't* work if I was returning the output.  Mega bonus-points to whoever can describe that to me.

Edit:
Borked the `diff` - you need to add exception handlers for `InstantiationException`, `IllegalAccessException` and `ClassNotFoundException` as well.  Your IDE should prompt you of this though.

Comment: First of all, you don't need the `newInstance();`. You only need to load the class, no instances are necessary. Secondly, the whole line shouldn't even be necessary with any recent platform (this may be GWT related), since the driver class is automagically retrieved according to the prefix of the JDBC url (jdbc:mysql).